# Condense similiar methods into one mega cool method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove duplicated code and run into an issue here:

I've got five very similar entities (different asset types, e.g. Bonds, Stocks). The methods I'm trying to condense return some statistics about these assets. The statistics are obtained with the help of Linq, the queries are almost identical.

**Before**, I had five separate methods in my controller (e.g. BondStatistics, StockStatistics). One of these would look like this (db is my database context which has each asset type defined):

```
    public JsonResult BondStatistics()
    {
        var items = db.Bonds.ToList();
        var result = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    key = "Bonds",
                    values = items.Select(i => 

                        new {
                            x = i.priceChangeOneDayInEuro,
                            y = i.priceChangeTotalInEuro,
                            size = i.TotalValueInEuro,
                            toolTip = i.Description
                        }
                    )
                },
            };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I googled that one way to rewrite these into just one method could be using reflection. However, I thought I could use a dirty shortcut, something like this:

```
public JsonResult Scatter(string asset)
{
    if (asset == "Stocks") { var items = db.Stocks.ToList(); };
    if (asset == "Bonds") { var items = db.Bonds.ToList(); };
    if (asset == "Futures") { var items = db.Futures.ToList(); };
    if (asset == "Options") { var items = db.Options.ToList(); };
    if (asset == "Funds") { var items = db.Funds.ToList(); }

    var result = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                key = asset,
                values = items.Select(i => 
                    new {
                        x = i.priceChangeOneDayInEuro,
                        y = i.priceChangeTotalInEuro,
                        size = i.TotalValueInEuro,
                        toolTip = i.Description
                }
            )
        },
    };
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This leads to the problem that the type of "items" is not known in the Linq query at design time.

What would be a good way to overcome this problem? Use some totally other pattern, do use reflection or is there an easy fix?

**EDIT**
As suggested, I created an Interface and let the BaseAsset-class implement it. Then, changing the condensed method to

```
List<IScatter> items = new List<IScatter>();
if (asset == "Stocks") { items = db.Stocks.ToList<IScatter>(); };
if (asset == "Bonds") { items = db.Bonds.ToList<IScatter>(); };
if (asset == "Futures") { items = db.Futures.ToList<IScatter>(); };
if (asset == "Options") { items = db.Options.ToList<IScatter>(); };
if (asset == "Funds") { items = db.Funds.ToList<IScatter>(); }
```

works, at design time at last. Thank you very much!

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question as it is currently "primarily opinion-based" and could end up being closed for that reason.

Comment: Would the `GetObject` method work for you here? So instead of doing the if statements, try `var entity = db.GetObject(asset); var items = db.entity.ToList();` This is completely untested and just a suggestion.

Comment: Note that `items` variable(s) only exist inside the curly braces of the respective if statements. In the Linq code, the variable `items` is not declared.

Comment: @elgonzo, yes, but I cannot write it outside either, because then it is of type List<Bond> e.g. and I cannot reassign it to List<Stock>.

Comment: I see. Do Bond and Stock (and the other elements) share a common base class?

Comment: Indeed they do, they all derive from the class "BaseAsset". The Method "TotalValueInEuro" is defined not therein, but in each separate asset-class.

Comment: And the properties you access in the Linq query are actually declared in the "BaseAsset" type?

Comment: All but "TotalValueInEuro" are derived 1:1 from the BaseClass. TotalValueInEuro is not because its calculation is different depending on the specific asset.

Comment: @peter That's precisely what interfaces are for! When you want to say there's a common member on several types, but that the implementation for each may be different

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with an interface, then!

Comment: Make "TotalValueInEuro" also an "abstract" property in BaseClass, like `public abstract int TotalValueInEuro { get; }`

Comment: @elgonzo Yeah, that's another way of doing it. Generally I think it's preferable to use an interface unless there's a good reason to do it in an abstract class instead, but it often isn't too important either way

Comment: @BenAaronson, agreed. I just try to keep the proposed change to Peter's code to a minimum (i did not notice your comment and Peters response when i typed my comment), since the comment section is on the fringe of becoming a discussion ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting everything into `var`, but what exactly is the type of the items you are processing?

If it would be `List<Stock>` for `db.Stocks.ToList()`, `List<Bond>` for `db.Bonds.ToList()` you can simply define an interface (e.g. `IHasPriceInformation`) which has the fields you are using in the LINQ query. Then, Let `Stock`, `Bond` and others implement this interface (or provide an abstract base implementation of them) and simply run your LINQ Query on a `List<IHasPriceInformation>`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try and make first contact with interfaces.

Comment: Interfaces are great, saved me lot of redundant code ... IHasCheeseburger!